# Adding click event to image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I am new in objective c.I have an image and i want to show some alert message when i click on it
Added image like this-

```
AHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, 40, 40)];
    UIImage *imageA = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.png"];
    AHolder.image = imageA;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(aPressed:) name:@"aPressed" object:nil];
    [view addSubview:AHolder]
```

And its event like this-

```
 -(IBAction)aPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hello" message:@"a pressed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancle" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

It doesn't give me any error but also when i click on the image nothing happens.
Please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add tap gestures to the image view .

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[AHolder setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[AHolder addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

-(void)handleTapGesture{
//do what ever you want here
}
```

Otherwise, simply use button with background image.

Answer (score 0):

Use tapGestureRecognizer. so whenever user taps the iamgeview, you can do what ever you want

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(aPressed)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[aHolder setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[aHolder addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)aPressed{
//do what ever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and most popular solution to your question would be to use a custom UIButton over your image.
Then just set the selector as your method you want to call on click of button. Make sure that the frame of UIButton & UIImage is same.

Answer (score 0):

Add "round rect button" object in the xib file. Set 'Type' attribute to 'custom', 'Background' attribute to 'nameofyourimage.extension'.

Connect aPressed: method to the touch up inside event of the round rect button.

Answer (score 0):

Need not to put `UIButton` over your image. Just use `UIButton` rather than `UIImageView`. You can set `UIButton` `backgroundimage` or `image` property to the image you want.

Other than this you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` like this:

Put this code to `viewDidLoad`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
[yourImage addGestureRecognizer:rec];
[yourImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; //!! this is important
```

and implement this delegate method

```
#define unused_related_to_gesture
- (void)tapRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStateBegan\n");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled\n");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStateChanged\n");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStateEnded\n");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStateFailed\n");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStatePossible\n");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nUIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized\n");
        // this section will contain your code of clicking the image.
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hello" message:@"a pressed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancle" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```